# Java: different Chain Stream and Connection Stream

Tags: java, file-io, stream

I have read a document that they say:

> In java there two types of Stream: Chain Stream and Connection Stream.

Although I google but I see no result about this concept.

So, is it true ? If true, please explain for me.

Comment: What document are you reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is using the term "Chain Stream" as a technical term but rather "chain" and "stream" as technical terms.

A Chain is a series of components which link together.

A Connection could be referring to a component which connects to a resource outside Java.

Answer (score 3):

`Chain Streams` are that streams that are using the output of another stream as their input in the pipe. (Example: BufferdInputStream) `Connection Streams` are the streams at the root of the pipe. (Example: FileInputStream)

Comment: Yes. you say right about how to use it. But can you tell me more, please. But strange thing is I don't see anything else say about those concepts

Comment: I did not tell you how to use them. I told about the difference. The chained ones are build on other streams and the other are at the source: a file, a socket or whatever. What do you want to know further?

Comment: ah. I understand your idea. I have understood about those concepts. because the concept is same with the way they work :)

Comment: Nothing really magic though, but can be powerful. :) If you're googling then look for `java stream chaining` or `java stream pipe`. You'll get more useful results, I bet.

Answer (score 2):

§  A Connection Stream is basically a link that actually connects your program  to the external resource(like Files, Network Sockets). Ex: FileOutputStream.

§  A Chained Stream is like a dependent connection that uses an underlying Connection Stream or another Chained Stream to receive output or feed input in order to complete end to end connection. Ex: ObjectOutputStream.